# How to add "throw exception" to this code?

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, bluej

This is my code

```
 public int Test(int[]n){
    if(n.length!=0){
        int smallest = n[0];
        for(int i = 0; i<n.length ; i++){
            if(smallest > n[i]){
                smallest = n[i];
                return smallest; 
            }else{
            return 0; 
        }
    }

}
```

How do I change this code so that it throws an exception instead of returning zero if the list is empty?

Comment: why do you have an 'int' return type when you dont want to return one?

Comment: ops my bad! forgot the return statement!

Comment: @In6ify which exception do you want to throw?

Answer (score 3):

you can simply achieve your goal:

```
 public int Test(int[] n) {
    if (n.length != 0) {
        int smallest = n[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            if (smallest > n[i]) {
                smallest = n[i];
            }
        }
        return smallest;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("List is empty!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the else block as follows :

```
if(n.length!=0){
    int smallest = n[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<n.length ; i++){
        if(smallest > n[i]){
            smallest = n[i];
            return smallest; // you might want to change this as well as suggested by @saeid
        } else {
            throw new CustomException(); 
        }
    }
}
```

where `CustomException` can extend any exception that you might want to throw.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for the empty list, and if it's empty simply throw an exception.

```
    throw new Exception("Your message that you want to show whenever the list is empty").
```

or else

Create a custom exception class.

```
    class ListIsEmptyException extends Exception{
       //create constructors as per your need
    }
```

Now if list is empty

```
    throw new ListIsEmptyException();
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement can not be in inner "if block" since it returns if first comparison success.But it depends on your requirement where you have to return the method. Try this code

create a custom exception

public class customException{

```
public customException(String msg) {

    super(msg);
}
```

}

```
if(n.length!=0){
    int smallest = n[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<n.length ; i++){
        if(smallest > n[i]){
            smallest = n[i];
            return smallest; 
        }else{
            throw new customException("Its an empty list!!!"); 
    }
}
```